# Having trouble using the compareTo method

Tags: java, compare

Hey all I've recently been trying to learn the compareTo method but this is extremely confusing.
The goal of this program was to hardcode information into a array of objects and sort it by the test score. The problem is compareTo method which I'm having trouble creating since the book I'm using doesn't go in to detail about this method.  Here is the code so far.

````
public class janesj_Lab7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    CS_UnderGradStudent no1 = new CS_UnderGradStudent(101,"Nancy","Brown","abc@kean.edu",70.0);
    CS_UnderGradStudent no2 = new CS_UnderGradStudent(102,"John", "May","def@kean.edu",90);
    CS_GradStudent no3 = new CS_GradStudent(103,"William","Smith","xyz@kean.edu",70,"Database");
    Object[] arrays = new Object[3];
    arrays[0] = no1;
    arrays[1] = no2;
    arrays[2] = no3;
    int x = (int)Student.getGrade();
    Arrays.sort(arrays,0,3);
    for(int i = 0;i<arrays.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(arrays[i].toString());
    }
    }



        public static abstract class Student implements Comparable<Student>{
        public static int studentId;
        public static String firstName;
        public static String lastName;
        public static String email;
        public static double testScore;
        public static String STUDENT_TYPE;

        public static double getGrade(){
        return testScore;
        }
        public static String getStudent() {
        return STUDENT_TYPE;
        }




        public Student(int id,String fname, String lname, String email, double testScore){
        this.studentId = id;
        this.firstName = fname;
        this.lastName = lname;
        this.email =email;
        this.testScore = testScore;
        }







        @Override
        public String toString() {
        String x = Double.toString(testScore);
        return "\tStudent ID: " + studentId + " name: "+ firstName + ","+ lastName + " Email: " + email + " testScore: " + x;
        }
        public abstract String computeGrade();
        }

        public static class CS_UnderGradStudent  extends Student  implements Comparable<Student>{
        String STUDENT_TYPE ="CS_UnderGradStudent";
        public CS_UnderGradStudent(int id,String fname, String lname, String email, double testScore) {
        super(id,fname,lname,email,testScore);
        }

        public String computeGrade() {
        if( testScore>=70) {
        return "Pass";
        }
        else {
        return "Fail";
        }
        }
        public String toString(){
        String x = Double.toString(testScore);
        return"student type: " + STUDENT_TYPE + "\n" + super.toString() + "\n\t" + "Grade: " + computeGrade();
        }
        }
        public static class CS_GradStudent extends Student implements Comparable<Student>{
        String STUDENT_TYPE = "CS_GradStudent";
        String researchTopic;
        public CS_GradStudent(int id,String fname, String lname, String email, double testScore,String r) {
        super(id,fname,lname,email,testScore);
        researchTopic = r;
        }
        public String computeGrade() {
        if(testScore>= 80) {
        return "Pass";
        }
        else {
        return "Fail";
        }
        }
        public String toString() {
        String x = Double.toString(testScore);

        return"student type: " + STUDENT_TYPE + "\n" + super.toString() + "\n" + "Grade: " + computeGrade() + "\nResearch Topic: " + researchTopic;
        }

        }


        }
        ```
````

Comment: if a < b return -1, if b > a return 1 else return 0

Comment: You don't need to declare that the subclasses of student implement comparable. Student is comparable, so all its subclasses are too.